# Persisting app.config variables in updates via Click once deployment

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2005, clickonce

Every time a new update is released for an application with click once, the variables in the app.config file are destroyed

```
<userSettings>
    <app.My.MySettings>
      <setting name="Email" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </app.My.MySettings>
  </userSettings>
```

How can i prevent that?

Is there any way of feching the variables from the previous application version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have the "Applications should check for updates" option checked?

Have a look at [Exploring Secrets of Persistent Application Settings](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33944/1954) (the section titled "Maintaining Settings Between Program Versions"):

> For any settings from the current
>   version that match settings in the
>   prior version, this routine will
>   import them into the current version's
>   user.config file:

At the entry point to your program, place the following code.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeSettings) 
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
   Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeSettings = false;
}
```

Note that UpgradeSettings is a boolean **user** setting (not application) that you need to add yourself, and you want the default value to be `True`.

Comment: Note that UpgradeSettings is a boolean setting that you need to add yourself, and you want the default value to be True. (This is explained in the article.)

Comment: Weirdly my if statement always has reads Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeSettings as false even when the default value is True. I had to change the setting to be named "upgrade_settings" for it to be read as True,

Comment: In WPF there is no **[APPname]**.Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeSettings function 
 but **[Applicationname]**.Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() exists  and it is void function what should I have to @Mitch Wheat, Is it outdated in 2020, vs2019, .net 4.7 ?