# How to preserve app.config between ClickOnce app updates?

Tags: c#, clickonce

My ClickOnce app includes an `app.config` file, which the app does modify according to the user's preferences.  It appears, though, that every time my clients get a new version of the app, the `app.config` file gets reset to its original state.

Is there any way to preserve the `app.config` file between ClickOnce updates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persisting app.config variables in updates via Click once deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622764/persisting-app-config-variables-in-updates-via-click-once-deployment)

Comment: At first I agreed that it is a duplicate - but on seeing @Daniel's answer, I think this is worth keeping open because it makes the point about using .settings files rather than app.config for what I'm trying to do...

Comment: My answer is only a workaround for the problem you're facing. IMO a .settings file with properties using user scope is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app.config is used to store application configurations. For user custom configurations you should be using a .settings file.

The only way I know to keep the user app config is to save a copy of the file before publishing and, post publishing, replace the

> publish_dir/version_dir/app.config.deploy

with the copy.

Comment: please more comprehensive answer didn't understand, Explanation needed