# Save Settings.settings in C# not persisting between sessions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have searched everywhere and everyone says the same thing about saving to the settings.settings file but if I "save" a setting, close the application and then open it then the setting is still what it used to be.

The setting is set to scope "user"

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ContactPerson = value;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Is this in a debug build running in VS?

Comment: Yes, should I change it to release?

Comment: This work for me with no issue.  I'm using VS 2012.  The config file is getting buried deep into `C:\Users\davidcr\AppData\Local...`  The main app.config file will retain the default setting value.

Comment: @JcMey3r: What you are seeing is that if you change you application and recompile it, the framework will create a new folder for your settings and create a new set of default settings each time. It is saving it, it's just that you are not running the same application. If you look under `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\ ` you'll probably find a bunch of folders that have names like `yourapp.exe_Url_<bunch of random characters>` that contain settings for different builds.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/622813/622391) of use - it explains how to import settings from a prior version of your application